# Quickly retreive 512px image thumbnail/preview from 10GB+ PSB on MacOS?

Tags: macos, images, adobe-photoshop, metadata, python3

#### Is it possible to quickly (milliseconds) extract a 512px image thumbnail/preview from large images (10GB+ PSBs) on MacOS?

---

##### Use Case

I need to quickly get an image preview/thumbnail (~512px) of a batch of large multi-GB images on import into FileMaker to accompany metadata that is accessed with the aid of ExifTool.

##### Source Images

The original images could be as large as 10GB+, 8-bit to 32-bit, RGB or CMYK, layered or flattened, with or without Alpha/Spot Changes, with or without background transparency, and are saved from Photoshop as either TIFs, PSDs, PSBs, PNGs, JPEGS, or HEICs with Thumbnails and Maximize Compatibility enabled.

##### Experimentation

**ExifTool** can generate 160px thumbnails from the embedded -PhotoshopThumbnails tag, but that’s smaller than I’d like:

```
exiftool -b -PhotoshopThumbnail in_path > out_path
```

If the ExifTool output below captures everything, the only thumbnail tag in the metadata is -PhotoshopThumbnail, which again is too small:

```
exiftool -a -b -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -preview:all DIR
```

**QuickLook** has limited success getting 512px images with this code:

```
qlmanage -t source_path_to_file -s 512 -o out_path
```

Unfortunately, QuickLook has problems with larger PSBs (starts having challenges at 2.12GB, and >4.3GB+ will fail). It also doesn't always play well with TIFFs (particularly CMYK with Alpha and/or Spot Channels), or if they are over 2GB. The same is true of Sips, which is even more finicky about first converting to RGB color space, etc., and starts losing the ability to retrieve other metadata as the files get into the 4.3GB+ range.

- **ImageMagick** is too slow when working with multi-GIG PSBs and it’s not feasible to generate from Photoshop.
- **Adobe Bridge** seems to be able to get large previews quickly of 10GB+ files when set to process files this big. How does it do that/where does that data come from? Is there a way to replate that outside of Bridge? JavaScript?
- **MacOS Finder Preview** also is unable to generate previews of PSBs that get into the ~4.5GB range.

Any other ideas that might work in combination with FileMaker to quickly access/produce previews/thumbnails on 10GB+ PSBs in the 512px range? AppleScript? JavaScript? Python? PIL Library?

Comment: Depending on your storage device 10GB is going to take *at least* one full second to load into memory, and that assumes you have a 10GB/s PCIe 5 SSD and that's going to be unlikely on anything except bleeding edge hardware at the moment. On an older SSD that would be 2 seconds or more just for the raw data needed to generate a thumbnail. Just picking out 512 pixels from arbitrary points in an image is not going to give you a good thumbnail so on top of that 10GB you will also need to do some computational resizing which also takes time. Your milliseconds requirement is optimistic at best.

Comment: I was hoping there was composite data (larger than the 160px thumbnail) stored somewhere within the file that could be read to speed it up.